# PostgreSQL Rails has_many :through / collection_singular_ids / :order problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, has-many, has-many-through

In the process of migrating to heroku, I have a weird error only when I use PostgreSQL (works fine in Mysql)

When I execute `@user.county_ids` I get the following error:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

`LINE 1: ...id" WHERE ("activity_areas".user_id = 1) ORDER BY counties.n...`

The generated sql request is :

`SELECT DISTINCT "activity_areas".county_id FROM "activity_areas" INNER JOIN "counties" ON "counties"."id" = "activity_areas"."county_id" WHERE ("activity_areas".user_id = 1) ORDER BY counties.name ASC`

and finally the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activity_areas
  has_many :counties, :through => :activity_areas
end

class ActivityArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :county

  default_scope joins(:county).order("counties.name ASC")
end

class County < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activity_areas
  has_many :users, :through => :activity_areas

  default_scope :order => 'name ASC'
end
```

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to PostgreSQL, ensure that the elements in order by clause are also present in the select clause. MySQL is kinda lenient on this rule :)

Try changing the default scope in activity area model to

```
default_scope select('counties.name').joins(:county).order("counties.name ASC")
```

This should generate a SQL like

```
SELECT DISTINCT "activity_areas".county_id, counties.name FROM "activity_areas"...
```

Comment: Dexter, it's not working. Here is the error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DISTINCT" LINE 1: SELECT counties.name, DISTINCT "activity_areas".county_id FR...` . The generated sql is `SELECT counties.name, DISTINCT "activity_areas".county_id FROM "activity_areas" INNER JOIN "counties" ON "counties"."id" = "activity_areas"."county_id" WHERE ("activity_areas".user_id = 1) ORDER BY counties.name ASC`